# Not able to connect to mysql database in jelastic

Tags: mysql, jelastic

i am not able to connect to mysql database which i imported from my system.i have added user to my imported database and giving the same user name and password in code yet there is no connection from my war app to database.my war app is retrieving nothing from imported multiclouddata database
my code as follows....
(i am a trial user)

```
package DBClass;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DataBaseClass 
{
Connection con=null;
Statement st=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
String host="jdbc:mysql://mysql-userapp.jelastic.servint.net/MultiCloudData";
    String username="test1";
    String password="LQ53fvGRYryyaveW";
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
PreparedStatement pst;
public Connection getConnection()
{
    try
    {

        Class.forName(driver);

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(host ,username,password);
        System.out.println("Connection is ok......");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

Comment: What errors do you receive? Did you try using the root MySQL user/password (just for a test - obviously should not use that for production!), to rule out the user as a possible cause?

Comment: yes i just now tried that alternative to..nothing is happening.i had set username root and password tat i received in my mail.                            i receive error in page displayed because i coded like that if connection credetials are wrong then this page will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the SQLException to find out the root cause of the problem.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

Connection conn = null;
...
try {
    conn =
       DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?" +
                                   "user=monty&password=greatsqldb");

    // Do something with the Connection

   ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    // handle any errors
    System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
```

More code examples:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html (above example is from this MySQL docs link)

When you have the exact error, it should be easy to fix the problem. Without it everything is just guesswork unfortunately!